# Setting the marginStart on a MaterialCheckBox programmically doesn't set the margins

Tags: android, android-layout

AS 2020.3.1

Trying to programmatically set the start margin on a MaterialCheckBox that I am programmatically adding to a layout.

This is my layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_category_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/llCategories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the snippet of code I am using to set the margins

```
mapOfCategoryFilters.value.forEach { childCategoryItem ->
    val chkChildCategory = MaterialCheckBox(context)
    chkChildCategory.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black))
    chkChildCategory.text = childCategoryItem.label

    val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    layoutParams.setMargins(32, 0, 0, 0)
    chkChildCategory.layoutParams = layoutParams
    llCategories.addView(chkChildCategory)
}
```

I have also tried the following which didn't work.

```
val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
layoutParams.setMargins(32, 0, 0, 0)
llCategories.addView(chkChildCategory, layoutParams)
```

The reason I need to set programmatically, as I would to indent some based on a condition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
val layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

You are using *LinearLayout.LayoutParams*.